# fuelphpでテスト実行時のモデル経由でのDBアクセス

Tags: php, テスト, fuelphp

Fuelphpのテスト実行に関して

Modelを使用してDBアクセスを行っているのですが、
テスト時のみ開発用DBに接続してテストするのではなく、
インメモリのDBを使用してテストしたいと思っています。

FuelphpはSqliteに対応しているようなのでそちらは問題ないのですが、
以下の仕組みが無いか探しています。
・テスト実行時、データベースに初期データを流し込む
・モデル経由でDBにアクセスし、データを取得、更新、削除等のテストをする
・テスト終了時、データをクリアする

初期データはJson、Yaml等の形式で保存しておいて、流し込むという風にできればいいなと考えています。

イメージとしましてはJavaのPlayframeworkのテスト実行をイメージしています。
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/ja/1.2.x/test

単純にDBのテストするだけならphpunitの仕組みでなんとかなるのではないかと思っているのですが、
ドキュメントを読んだだけだとこの仕組みで具体的にどう実装すればいイイのかがわかりません。
https://phpunit.de/manual/current/ja/database.html

具体的にどういう実装をすればいいのか、
やり方の書いてある資料の場所などご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけると助かります。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: http://qiita.com/flexfirm/items/9ad6a9d41caf10935d39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DbUnitでももちろん可能ですが、複雑なので自作する方法を
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/Kenji_s/20111110/1320922825
で解説しています。

Comment: ありがとうございます！お恥ずかしながら、taskの機能は初めて知りました。